# spring cache and aspectj

Tags: spring, caching, aspectj

I want to use @cacheable annotations on objects that are not managed by spring. I am using the maven-aspectj compiler to complile the classes. But i dont see anything getting woven.

I dont have an @Aspect,as I am assuming spring should take care of this for all cache related annotations. I have the following in my config file.

I made couple of change after googling

```
<cache:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.merc.spring.cache.aspectj" />
```

added a aop.xml in META-INF folder with following in it

```
<aspectj>
<weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
  <include within="com.merc.spring.cache.aspectj..*"/>
</weaver>
</aspectj>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to validate if your @Cacheable classes are actually getting weaved with the CacheAspect, you can add this to the maven aspectj plugin:

```
<configuration>
    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
```

**EDIT**

I am pasting my entire aspectj plugin configuration, this works for me in a project:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outxml>true</outxml>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

my java.version, aspectj.version is set to:

```
<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.6.12</aspectj.version>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Oh, okay, you have spring-aspects in your classpath right? either that could be missing or the way you have configured the aspectj plugin - it should have worked otherwise